# Apache access log strange entries

Tags: apache-2.2

I have been having high load on the cpu of my ubuntu server so I was checking the apache access logs. I noticed this entry over and over it pretty much fills the access log. Any ideas what this could be? we run a wordpress site with quite a few plugins. but the site itself is not really open the public, so we don't get that many visitors.

209.236.116.42 - - [10/Aug/2014:07:16:51 -0700] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 5088 "-" "-"
209.236.116.42 - - [10/Aug/2014:07:16:51 -0700] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 5088 "-" "-"
209.236.116.42 - - [10/Aug/2014:07:16:52 -0700] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 5088 "-" "-"
209.236.116.42 - - [10/Aug/2014:07:16:53 -0700] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 5088 "-" "-"
209.236.116.42 - - [10/Aug/2014:07:16:54 -0700] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 5088 "-" "-"
209.236.116.42 - - [10/Aug/2014:07:16:55 -0700] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 5088 "-" "-"
209.236.116.42 - - [10/Aug/2014:07:16:56 -0700] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 5088 "-" "-"
209.236.116.42 - - [10/Aug/2014:07:16:57 -0700] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 5088 "-" "-"
209.236.116.42 - - [10/Aug/2014:07:16:58 -0700] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 5088 "-" "-"

Answer (score 3):

It is a brute-force attempt on your wordpress login. Pretty much every wordpress site gets such attempts. Since yours has a low volume of legit traffic, the illegit traffic sticks out like a sore thumb more.

Hopefully your passwords are good, otherwise its probably already someone else's wordpress site, if you get my drift.

Also, you might want to consider using fail2ban.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody is hammering you from 209.236.116.42 (www.profsl.com). Once a minute isn't really a DOS frequency; but your site is *really* open to the public...